# SQL relationship for nested groups

Tags: mysql, hierarchy

I'm working on a creating a database schema for a legacy app that currently saves its data to XML files.

I'm having trouble representing this relationship:

```
Task Group 1 contains
|-- Simple Task 1
|-- Simple task 2
|-- Task Group 1a contains
    |-- Simple Task 3
    |-- Simple Task 4
    |-- Task Group 1b contains
        |--Simple task 5
```

Basically, a task group may contain one or more tasks.  These may be simple tasks or other task groups.   So the nested groups is what I'm having trouble with.

This is what I have so far:

```
CREATE TABLE `task_group` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `processing_type` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `notes` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_parent_idx` (`parent_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_parent` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `task_group` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: And what is exactly the problem?  Do you think this do not cover what you need? It is not working? It is a traditional hierarchical table.

Answer (score 1):

It may help to separate the hierarchy from the task-like objects, and implement them as inherited types. There would be four tables.

```
TaskTrees
  ParentTaskId   references Tasks.TaskId
  ChildTaskId    references Tasks.TaskId

Tasks
  TaskId
  TaskType      simple or group

GroupTasks
  TaskId   references Tasks.TaskId
  <group specific columns>

SimpleTasks
  TaskId   references Tasks.TaskId
  <other specific columns>
```

This way the Trees become simple hierarchies of "things" and don't much care what those things are. There are [other ways](https://www.elsevier.com/books/joe-celkos-trees-and-hierarchies-in-sql-for-smarties/celko/978-0-12-387733-8) to implement trees than this.

The domain-specific information is held in GroupTasks and SimpleTasks. This is where the values required to implement each is held. There are [other ways](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=inheritance) to implement inheritance. I'm not sufficiently versed in MySQL to recommend one over another.

Integrity between the tables must be maintained through the application. Ensuring a simple task does not have children, for example, is not guaranteed through the data model alone.